# Logging to multiple files AND the console

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to using the `logging` module in Python to log to files and the console as well. Here's what I have so far:

```py
# configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

# main file logger
main_file_logger = logging.getLogger('main_file')
main_file_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('logs/main.log'))

def loggingHelper(message, level='info', submission_id=None):
    method_name = level.lower().strip()
    if method_name not in ['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'critical']:
        method_name = 'info'

    if not submission_id:
        method_callable = getattr(main_file_logger, method_name)
        method_callable(message)
    else:
        submission_file_logger = logging.getLogger(f'submission_{submission_id}_file')
        submission_file_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(f'logs/submission_{submission_id}.log'))

        method_callable = getattr(submission_file_logger, method_name)
        method_callable(message)
```

What I want to accomplish is this: Everytime I call loggingHelper, I want to print a message to the console. In addition to that, I want to print the same thing to `logs/main.log`. So the console and `main.log` should get the same thing. Finally, if a `submission_id` is specified, I want to also create a file called `submission_id.log` and I want to also log the message on that file (while also logging to the console and `main.log`).

After setting this up, I ran the following lines of code:

```py
from utils import loggingHelper

loggingHelper('1', level='debug')
loggingHelper('2', level='info')
loggingHelper('3', level='warning', submission_id=3)
loggingHelper('4', level='critical', submission_id=4)
loggingHelper('5', level='debug')
```

This printed what I wanted to the console:

```
2021-08-19 10:10:01,966: DEBUG: 1
2021-08-19 10:10:01,966: INFO: 2
2021-08-19 10:10:01,967: WARNING: 3
2021-08-19 10:10:01,968: CRITICAL: 4
2021-08-19 10:10:01,968: DEBUG: 5
```

But `main.log` looks like this:

```
1
2
5
```

and `submission_3.log` looks like this:

```
3
```

and `submission_4.log` looks like this:

```
4
```

None of the log files have the proper formatting. Also, the main log is missing all the log messages that are printed to `submission_3.log` and `submission_4.log`. I've tried a few different configurations but none of them work the way I want them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, fixed it. Here's how I did it:

```py
# configure logging
LOGGING_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
LOGGING_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(LOGGING_FORMAT)
LOGGING_LEVEL_THRESHOLD = logging.DEBUG

logging.basicConfig(level=LOGGING_LEVEL_THRESHOLD, format=LOGGING_FORMAT)

# main file logger
main_file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs/main.log')
main_file_handler.setFormatter(LOGGING_FORMATTER)

main_logger = logging.getLogger('main')
main_logger.setLevel(LOGGING_LEVEL_THRESHOLD)
main_logger.addHandler(main_file_handler)

def loggingHelper(message, level='info', submission_id=None):
    method_name = level.lower().strip()
    if method_name not in ['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'critical']:
        method_name = 'info'

    method_callable = getattr(main_logger, method_name)
    method_callable(message)

    if submission_id:
        submission_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f'logs/submission_{submission_id}.log')
        submission_file_handler.setFormatter(LOGGING_FORMATTER)

        submission_file_logger = logging.getLogger(f'submission_{submission_id}')
        submission_file_logger.setLevel(LOGGING_LEVEL_THRESHOLD)
        submission_file_logger.propagate = False
        submission_file_logger.addHandler(submission_file_handler)

        method_callable = getattr(submission_file_logger, method_name)
        method_callable(message)
```